# What is the module-path to the top-level module?

Tags: module, scope, racket

The documentation for [`module*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/module.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._module%2A%29%29) says that it can `require` the enclosing module. How can it require the enclosing module, or require a module defined in the top-level module in its source file?

```
#lang racket

(provide inner)

(module inner racket
  (provide abc)
  (define abc 123))

(module* main racket
  (require 'inner)   ; <----- What goes here?
  (print abc))
```

I've tried a whole bunch of things for the argument to `require` and for the second argument to `module*`, so far with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(require (submod ".." inner))`

See the documentation for *module paths* here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-paths.html.